# Dependencies Injection error in modules

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have the module of my application:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.controllers','app.routes','app.services']);
```

I have my services module:

```
angular.app('app.services', [])
    .factory('usuarioService', ['$rootScope', 'renderService',
        function($rootScope, renderService){
            // logic of factory
    }]);

angular.module('app.services', [])
    .factory('renderService', ['$http',
        function($http){
            // logic of factory
    }]);
```

and I have my controller:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.services'])
    .controller('meuCtrl',
        ['$scope','$rootScope','usuarioService','renderservice',
            function($scope, $rootScope, usuarioService, renderService){
               // logic of controller
    }]);
```

But to run the application, I get dependencies injection error:

```
Unknown provider: usuarioServiceProvider <- usuarioService <- meuCtrl
```

I do not understand what might be going on, as do the injection into appropriate location.

unless I'm doing wrong these injections.

PS .: All .JS files are being loaded into index.html, none have been forgotten.

Comment: `angular.app` is not a function. Check your browsers dev console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `usuarioService` factory declaration is incorrectly adding itself to a non-existent member of the `angular` object.

You have:

`angular.app('app.services', []) // note the 'app' usage
    .factory('usuarioService', ['$rootScope', 'renderService',`

You should have

`angular.module('app.services', []) // note the 'module' usage
    .factory('usuarioService', ['$rootScope', 'renderService',`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
angular.module('app.services')
    .factory('renderService', ['$http', function($http) {
        //logic
        return renderService;
}]);


angular.module('app.services')
    .factory('usuarioService', ['$rootScope', 'renderService',function($rootScope,renderService) {
        //logic
        return renderService;
}]);

angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.services'])
    .controller('meuCtrl',
        ['$scope','$rootScope','usuarioService','renderservice',
            function($scope, $rootScope, usuarioService, renderService){
               // logic of controller
    }]);
```